# Calling a Sub or Function that sometimes doesn't exist

Tags: vba

I'm trying to create a macro (in PERSONAL.XLSB) that every time a workbook is opened, it checks a condition and in if it's true (this means the workbook opened contains an specific Sub), it calls this Sub.

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   Set App = Application

End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

   If condition Then Call Specific_Sub

End Sub
```

It runs fine when I open a file that contains that Sub, however, if the Sub is not in the file, the compiler returns the error “Sub or Function not defined”, naturally.

I’m trying very hard to find a way to do this and deal with the error, but `On error GoTo` doesn’t work because the compiler error is before the run time, so it’s not executed.
I guess I have to do this in a different way but I can’t picture how to do it, any help or ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have that code in your workbook, meaning you put it there, then you have the ability to put that sub. Just change the subroutines logic to do nothing or return a message in the event that you don't want it doing anything. This is a strange question.... it's like... "Why" would you build it this way.

Comment: You should be able to use: `Application.Run ("' & Wb.FullPath & '!"Specific_Sub")`. That will allow you to trap the error. But it is unclear from your question what exactly is happening with the workbooks - do you open new workbook manually, or from another workbook and where the checking code is.

Comment: You're using an application object to handle the "Workbook_Open" event, so are you doing this in an add-in (or something which serves a similar purpose)? Where is this other Sub you're calling? - in the same workbook as the posted code, or somewhere else?  Would help if you were to show some more of your code and added more detail to describe exactly what your use case is.

Comment: Maybe try to use [`CallByName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/callbyname-function)

Comment: Application.Run with an On Error Resume Next.

Comment: I apologise, my question wasn't totally clear. The code I posted is in PERSONAL.XLSB, so it can runs every time a workbook is opened. The Sub I'm calling is in some of the workbooks I open every day, they aren't under my control so I can't modifiy the code and I need to call this Sub from my side. As @Victor K, S Meaden and @mooseman suggested, using `Application.Run` is a very simple and good solution to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cobbled this together from a few web sites.  The key is that your sub routines name is in a variable and application. run uses the variable.  This gets past the compiler error you are running into

```
Sub SubExists()
        Dim ByModule As Object
        Dim ByModuleName As String
        Dim BySub As String
        Dim ByLine As Long
        '
        'Module and sub names
        ByModuleName = "Module1"
        BySub = "Specific_Sub"

        On Error Resume Next
        Set ByModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.vbComponents(ByModuleName).CodeModule
        ByLine = ByModule.ProcStartLine(BySub, vbext_pk_Proc)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Application.Run BySub
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

   SubExists

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers I've discovered that the best way is to use `Application.Run`. To keep the code as simple as possible, I just changed the last part to look like this:

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

   On Error Resume Next

   If condition Then
      Application.Run ("'" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "'!" & "Specific_Sub")
   End If

End Sub
```

Thank you all.